# PPTP/GRE Multi-forwarding NAT IPTables Example

Tags: linux, iptables, nat, ipsec, pptp

Google is showing me some returns on PPTP/GRE NAT through iptables/netfilter that will allow multiple connections.

However, I am not finding an example of using this pptp helper module that allows for this.  Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This changed radically in kernel 2.6.14, and that accounts for the various random documentation examples you're finding (many with the pre-2.6.14 syntax). I don't have a machine handy to test on, but you should be fine with loading `ip_conntrack_pptp` and `ip_nat_pptp` to get PPTP connection tracking.

Comment: Thanks this is a point in the right direction... will hold my accept to see if someone feels like spoonfeeding it to me :-)

Comment: `modprobe` 'em and give it a go... >smile<

Comment: Venturing into WDS with AIK right now ... This all seems really cool ... as long as it works :-)  Will give this a go later today hopefully.

Comment: Ahh... automated Windows deployment... joy that it is. Good luck.

Comment: How can I add those modules in ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you are talking about being behind a NAT, and trying to have multiple users connect to a remote VPN server, then I just managed to fix this on DD-WRT v24-sp2 (04/16/10):

Apparently the kernel modules were missing which do the NAT translation for the GRE protocol - inserting them proved enough. I have added the following lines to the firewall script:

```
# Insert modules for PPTP over NAT:
insmod nf_nat_proto_gre
insmod nf_conntrack_proto_gre
insmod nf_conntrack_pptp
insmod nf_nat_pptp
```

The rest of iptables/netfilter is already set up correctly in DD-WRT apparently :)

If wanted I can dig up the rest of the NAT table entries relating to this.

Comment: Is that a 2.4 or 2.6 kernel underneath day DD-WRT build? (I'm looking at their web site and having a *really* hard time telling.) A 2.4 kernel will do this completely differently than a >= 2.6.14 kernel.

Comment: Uname -a tells me it is running 2.6.24 - indeed 2.4 would be quite different - apparently a lot has changed, amongst others the modules have been renamed to the nf_ netfilter prefix.

Comment: You saved my day! My ISP provides internet access via PPTP channel, and the channel is kept up by home server. My job provides a VPN access to intranet via PPTP as well, and I couldn't connect to job PPTP VPN over my ISP PPTP. I googled for the solution several months, worked through my iptable rules uncountable times, and your solution made things work in the end! I added these modules to /etc/modprobe.d/pptp_nat.conf on my home server, and it works like a charm even after reboot! To complete the picture for guys who google around for the similar problem, my home server runs ArchLinux.

Comment: Like @kstep, this was working fine on my ArchLinux home server, but since I updated to kernel 4.7 last night, it just stopped working.